# Current Sensing Amplifier Circuit explained

Tags: analog, current-sensing

I've been trying to understand why each every comment is in the circuit shown. I understand that the amp is taking the voltage drop across the Rsense and amplifying it such that the current across it is known. However, I'm not sure why the two resistors are there because if I didn't know any better, I'd design with no resistors that way all the current is accounted for across Rsense. Also, I'm not sure how to analyze the BJT in the feedback loop.

I'm assuming the current mirror is there to provide a 1:n ratio current/mirror the current at the output. [image]

Comment: What device or publication is this figure from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RG2 is only there to make the circuit symmetrical so that input bias current of the amplifier cancels out.

From the current through the sense resistor to the load, there is a voltage drop such that the right hand side of the sense resistor is at a lower potential than the left hand side.

The op-amp drives the BJT base to equalize the voltage at the lower end of RG1 with the voltage at the right hand side of the sense resistor. That means that the collector current is equal to the load current multiplied by Rsense/RG1. The base current is relatively small, perhaps 0.3% of the collector current, so the emitter current is almost the same. So a resistor to ground can receive the sensed current and produce a ground-referenced voltage that can be buffered and fed to the output.

You may note that the current through the resistor RG1 does not pass through the sense resistor, that means that it represents the current through the load better than then current from the supply, but there is a proportionality between them, and typically RG1 = RG2 >> Rsense so it's a very minor difference.

I don't know why they show a "current mirror", it is not often used, but possibly some integrated circuits might use a  structure like that to deal with low supply voltages, reflecting the current off ground and supply again to get a voltage that can go a bit higher with respect to ground (the shown circuit produces a current with a compliance on the positive side that is limited by the op-amp output voltage and Vbe drop). For example, if the op-amp output can only get to Vin -1V then the maximum voltage at the emitter of the transistor is perhaps Vin - 2V, accounting for possible low-temperature operation where Vbe is large. That might be a bit tight if the circuit is intended to operate from a 3.3V or lower supply voltage.

Comment: Your synopsis of the current mirror is likely correct. It would give the output more dynamic range.

Comment: Thanks! It's starting to make a bit more sense. But why is RG1 and RG2 even there to begin with? It seems like the opamp is behaving like a voltage-controlled current source

Comment: RG1 sets the ratio of load current to sense current (collector and approximate emitter current of the transistor). So if 1A is flowing you might want 100uA for the sense current. So sense resistor of say 0.1 ohm and RG1 of 1K, so the collector current is 1/10,000 of the load current.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, the op-amp takes in the voltage difference caused by Rsense such that the op-amp output amplifies this difference to drive the BJT which will then cause a current to flow through it that corresponds to the current through Rsense?

Comment: That looks *very* similar to the LT6105 (Which I have used - very nice part). https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt6105.html

Comment: @KarinaRodriguez The op-amp forces the voltage drop across RG1 to be the same as the voltage drop across Rsense, which means that the collector current must be Iout*Rsense/RG1. Since Ib << Ic when the transistor is operating in active mode, the current from the emitter is about the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have redrawn the circuit below, to make it easy for me to analyze.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8s3vr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The op-amp (negative) feedback ensures that its inputs (nodes N1 and N2) are at the same potential (assuming gain is very high). Thus, assuming a current \$I_c\$ flows through Q1, potential at node N1 (same as at node N2) is:
$$V_{N1} = V_{N2} = V_c-I_cR_1$$
Since, no current flows through \$R_2\$, it has no potential drop across it. Thus, potential difference across \$R_s\$ is:
$$V_{Rs} = V_c - (V_c - I_cR_1) = I_cR_1$$
If current through \$R_s\$ is \$I_s\$, then,
$$I_sR_s = I_cR_1$$
$$I_c = \frac{I_sR_s}{R_1}$$
This current flows though Q2 (assuming \$\beta_1>> 1\$) whose output impedance, assuming its transconductance is \$g_{m2}\$, is \$\frac{1}{g_{m2}}\$.
Giving you the output voltage:
$$V_{o} = \frac{I_sR_s}{g_{m2}R_1}$$

Thus the output potential is proportional to \$I_s\$. I understand Q2 is not a current mirror, but I don't know how else this part would be implemented.
As, Spehro said R2 is probably added for symmetry, \$R_L\$ is required to ensure a current path for the sense current. And R1 is added to create the potential drop as explained above.